# How to modify string field in collection which resides in MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mlab

I have a collection in MongoLab called CollectionA.

In every document within this collectionA, i want to modify a field(say Field1 which is string) value from say "hello" to  "hello world"

What is the most efficient way to do it and from where should i make this change(from a c# console app or mongoLab interface?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually use the interactive `mongo` shell to do this.  Connect to your mongolab database using the connection details shown in the web UI.  Then, use an "update" command with a "$set" operator -- along the lines of the example at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/

For your example, it would be :

`db.collectionA.update( { Field1: "hello" }, { $set: { Field1: "hello world" } } );`